# raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord

In my index action, I have the following code:

```
@hotels = Hotel.where(lang: request.headers['Accept-Language']).includes(:contacts)
raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @hotels.blank?
```

I am raising the exception because I want it to be handled by an error handling code (based on rescue_from)

Is there a better way to write the code so that it does the same thing, i.e. raise the exception? I can do first! (notice the bang) when retrieving a single record, but as for collections, it seems like there is no way to do the same thing (no where!, all! ...)

Does it make sense at all?

Comment: Normally `includes` goes before `where` [proof](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can add `before_filter`

```
before_filter :check_hotels, :only => [:index]

def index
end

private

  def check_hotels
    @hotels = Hotel.where(lang: request.headers['Accept-Language']).includes(:contacts)
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "No hotels present." if @hotels.blank?
  end
```

Ofcourse you can give any path othet than `root_path`, its just an example I have shown

Answer (score 0):

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :blank_list

  private

 def blank_list
  logger.error "No Hotel Found With #{request.headers['Accept-Language']}"
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'No hotels present'
 end
end
```